# "Error: unknown type name ..." while working on a 1st-class ADT fused with a 2nd-class ADT.

Tags: c, windows, compiler-errors, codeblocks, abstract-data-type

Good morning everybody.

I'm new here on SO, and I'm asking this question because I have to readjust my Algorithms And Programming's exam of yesterday.
While typing my exam on CodeBlocks, I got an error I couldn't fix. Basically, the exam asked to load on memory some infos from a file (format: char *namecity, int population, int distance) in a data structure, and then it asked to calculate the mutual distances for each city and collect them in another data structure. I decided to make 2 ADTs: the first is defined in my library "vett.h":

```
#ifndef VETT_H_INCLUDED
#define VETT_H_INCLUDED
#include "List.h"

typedef struct vett
{
    char nome[21];
    int abitanti, dist;
    lista_t List;
} Item;

Item *vectInit(int N, Item *v);
Item *vectInsert(Item *v, char *nome, int people, int dist, int i);
#endif // VETT_H_INCLUDED
```

I made an "almost-ADT" or "2nd class ADT" (R.Sedgewick) based on my teacher lessons. Doing so, the main could create an array for that struct, and could have direct access to the fields of that struct; each "cell" contains: name of city, population, distance, and a List-type field. The problem begins here. 
To calculate and save the mutual distances of the cities, I decided to make another ADT list, type 1st class, in a library I called "List.h" :

```
#ifndef LIST_H_INCLUDED
#define LIST_H_INCLUDED

#include "vett.h"

typedef struct lista *lista_t;

lista_t calculateMutualDistance(lista_t List, Item *v, int N, int dist);
int chechForBetter(int SD, int i, int N, Item *v);
lista_t listInit(lista_t List, int N);

#endif // LIST_H_INCLUDED`
```

The file "List.c" contains the struct pointed in the .h file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "List.h"

typedef struct node *Node;
struct node
{
    char destination[21];
    int distance;
    Node next;
};

struct lista
{
    Node head, tail;
};

(...)
```

Now I got this error from CodeBlocks (in vett.h, line 9, after int abitanti, int dist):

" Error: unknown type name 'lista_t' ".

But why? lista_t is contained in List.c file and should be perfectly visible from "vett.h", because I included "List.h" and the pointer finds its struct in "List.c", which has got the "List.h" inclusion too!

Hope someone can explain it to me, because I have only 2 days to adjust the program and make it work, and it's quite huge. Thanks for the attention and sorry for my grammar errors, as you can tell I'm not English. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

It's typically a forward declaration problem. Just change your List.h file like this :

```
#ifndef LIST_H_INCLUDED
#define LIST_H_INCLUDED

typedef struct vett Item;
typedef struct lista *lista_t;

lista_t calculateMutualDistance(lista_t List, Item *v, int N, int dist);
int chechForBetter(int SD, int i, int N, Item *v);
lista_t listInit(lista_t List, int N);

#endif // LIST_H_INCLUDED`
```

Comment: The error disappeared, but I didn't understand what you did. In fact, you deleted the inclusion of vett.h in List.h; you added typedef struct vett Item, but aren't you creating a new Item which is confined to that library? I mean, you introduced a totally new Item which has nothing in common with the struct defined in vett.h: since you "isolated" List.h, aren't you creating an "empty copy" of the struct vett  ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You actually use a pointer to your struct Item.The compiler doesn't need the definition of this structure but just its existence. The item declared in List.h get enough informations to the compiler to validate your function declaration.

Comment: Ok, so i didn't know that; since I can't run the program because I'm still typing it, I was just asking myself how the compiler manages to "link" the two typedefs (the one which you put in List.h and the one that there's still in vett.h which is totally and completely specified/defined), since in "List.h" there isn't the inclusion of "vett.h". Thanks again.